# How can I concatenate multiple values in a single field or column? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, group-by, group-concat

I have a table in MySQL that needs to be grouped. I am **retrieving** sales order with **multiple items** ordered

My current database query looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, sales order **255 has 2 items bought** while sales order **300 has 3 items bought**

**Problem:** I need to **concatenate all product_id and their prices** in line_items field or **column according to their order_id**

The Output that I am desiring for is this:
[image]

This is the query that i used:

```
SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id, bsb.PRODUCT_ID AS product_id, bsb.PRICE AS   product_price, '' AS line_items
FROM bsb
INNER JOIN bso ON bso.ID = bsb. ORDER_ID
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID in(255, 300)
```

Kindly Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` inside `GROUP_CONCAT` to have your desired result set,but keep in mind `GROUP_CONCAT` has a default of 1024 characters to concatenate but it can be increased by following [*`GROUP_CONCAT`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) manual

```
SELECT bsb.ORDER_ID AS order_id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('product_id: ',bsb.PRODUCT_ID,' | ',bsb.PRICE) SEPARATOR ';') AS line_items
FROM bsb
INNER JOIN bso ON bso.ID = bsb. ORDER_ID
WHERE bsb.ORDER_ID in(255, 300)
GROUP BY bsb.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: Hi Khalid, Thanks for your response. Your answer is correct. You are awesome! :)